# using focus function with jquery live

Tags: jquery

I have a page in which i can successfully use the jquery focus function using live...

```
$(".comment_text_class").live('focus',
function() {
   //do something...
});
```

but when something comes into the page(ajax loading) the focus function doesn't work

as should be using the live function...

as suggested i used focusin function..

```
$(".comment_text_class").live('focusin',
function() {
   //do something...
});
```

but still new elements do not have the behavior...

also i want to hide something using the live function but it doesn't work at all..

even for the elements in the page itself...

```
   $(".comment_button").live('hide', function(){});
```

is the focus and hide function implemented at all by jquery 1.4.2 or is it a bug...
because the live focus was not working with jquery 1.4 version...

well the page here... http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/newuser.jsp?id=2

sorry .. fixed it out...

Please help...

thanks

Pradyut
India

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.4 or 1.4.2?

Comment: Sorry, what does "fixed it out" mean? Have you found an answer?

Comment: @fudgey was a problem with my page..now i fixed the prob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) doesn't work like you think I believe.  It doesn't watch for new elements and execute code, rather it waits or events to bubble up and acts upon them if the trigger element matches the selector.

`.live('focus')` and `.live('blur')` work in jQuery 1.4.1+, however you could use the `focusin` and `focusout` events in 1.4.0.

As for the `hide`, that's not an event.  If you're hiding all comments as soon as they're added, it seems like CSS is a better approach, like this:

```
.comment_button { display: none; }
```

Alternatively you can use the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) like this:

```
$(".comment_button").livequery(function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

Comment: @Pradyut - Can you post your ajax code? Something else seems to be interfering here.

Comment: well the page here...
http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/newuser.jsp?id=2

login using userid:gera@gear.com and password:12345

and then the shouts tab...

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.4.1, the focus event works with live handlers.
See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more info.